# I have problem while running my code in Appium

Tags: appium-android

The Error is:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: JAVA_HOME is not set currently. Please set JAVA_HOME.
 but I set JAVA_HOME on .profile

Answer (score 0):

Revisit your bash.profile file and check if you have mentioned JAVA HOME in the right format.

Another way is to add the path `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home` in the JAVA_HOME text field in 'Edit Configuration' window in [Appium app](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases/tag/v1.17.1-1) and try starting the server.

Screenshot below for your reference.

[image]